# Git: file on branch no longer wanted on branch

Tags: git

My branch "branch_a" has a file (file_a.txt) which should NOT be different from the like-named file on "master". I'd like to alter the branch in such a way that this changed file is removed from the branch, that is, so that the unchanged file from "master" is again present, NOT a changed branch of that file.  What I'm trying to avoid is having to maintain this file, which should never have been changed.

I thought at first git-reset might be helpful. Then I thought perhaps I should "git-rm" the file, but that will not leave me with the file at all.  I need to remove it from the branch, so that it is no longer a different version that that on "master".  What is the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you just need to reset that file back to the version on `master`, not erase any history of changes, correct? The former is easy, the latter requires history modification and should not be done lightly (especially if you've pushed the branch outside of your local repo).

To reset the contents of file `foo/bar/baz.txt` back to the state it has on `master`, just check out your branch and run

```
git checkout master -- foo/bar/baz.txt
```

This will grab the file from master, write it into your working copy, and stage it in the index. You can now just `git commit` that and your file will now match the one on `master`.

Comment: Yes, I believe this would have the same effect as what I want, but it isn't the same thing. For as soon as the file on master changes (upstream), I have to merge or rebase it again on my branch. I don't want to have to do this, because the branch I am working on is project-specific and only contains configuration changes, not code changes.  So I don't want this file to even be on the branch any longer.

Comment: @ckelly: I don't think you have any idea how VCS works. If *anything* changes on master, you don't see the change on your branch unless you merge the changes from master. What you're asking for is quite impossible.

Comment: Yes, Kevin. I'm quite new at Git. What I'm looking for is a new feature entirely.  So until "see-thru" branches are invented, I'll just have to rebase/merge regularly.